# Replicate record in OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am attempting to create a function that will duplicate an existing record using the laravel 'replicate' method.

Here is what I what but it's not working as expected.

```
updateContact.php

use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Input;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use Itinify\Itinify\Models\Contact;
use Itinify\Itinify\Models\Organisation;
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function replicateRecord()
    {
        $contact = Contact::find($this->param('id'));

        $newContact = $contact->replicate();

        $newContact->created_at = Carbon::now();

        $newContact->save();

        return Redirect::to('/contacts/'.$newContact->id);

    }
```

```
default.htm

<div class="col-md-12">
            <form data-request="replicateRecord">
                <button aria-label="" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Duplicate
                </button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass one param to the function (`$contact_id` or `$request`) in order to controller can understand which contact to replicate.

Make sure that contact table in your database does not have a UNIQUE column.
If has, to exclude one or more attributes from being replicated, you may pass an array to the `replicate` method:

```
$contact->replicate(['field']);
```

Remove this line (of course, it does not affect your problem):

```
$newContact->created_at = Carbon::now(); // not necessary
```